# Can connect, but not able to iterate or read data from MongoDB?

Tags: java, database, mongodb, exception, iteration

I have created class for mongodb connection:

```
public class DBConnect {

    MongoClient mongo = null;
    private String username = null;
    private String database = null;
    private String password = null;

    public DBConnect(String username, String database, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.database = database;
        this.password = password;
        this.connect();
    }

    private void connect() {

        try {
            MongoCredential credentials = MongoCredential.createScramSha1Credential(
                username, database, password.toCharArray());

            if (username.compareTo("DM") != 0
                    || database.compareTo("Admin") != 0
                    || password.compareTo("password") != 0) {
                System.out.println("Authentication failed");
            } else {

                MongoClientSettings.Builder builder = MongoClientSettings.builder().credential(credentials);

                mongo = MongoClients.create(builder.build());

                System.out.println("Connected to the database successfully");
            }

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {

            System.out.println("username, database, password can not be null");
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it from the main method of another class it works fine until collection iteration

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    // TODO code application logic here  

    DBConnect dbc = new DBConnect("DM", "Admin", "password");

    //Accessing the database
    MongoDatabase database = dbc.mongo.getDatabase("library");

    //Getting a collection
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("books");
    System.out.println("Collection success");

    FindIterable<Document> documents = collection.find();

    for (Document doc : documents) {

        System.out.println(doc);

    }
```

then it throws error

```
INFO: Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:2}] to 127.0.0.1:27017 because there was a socket exception raised by this connection.
Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='DM', source='Admin', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}
```

Why connection, accessing db, getting db goes smoothly but iteration throws error ?

Connects, access but do not let to operate over. Can't add, read, iterate, etc. Can anyone provide any directions ?

Comment: Connects, access but do not let to operate over. Can't add, read, iterate, etc. Can anyone provide any directions ?

Comment: This has to do with database security, I think. Please verify if the user has the appropriate role (privileges) to read or read/write to the database.

Comment: I run mongodb from command prompt like this >mongod --dbpath C:\Users\user\mongodb\data --auth. My guess that it provides authentation only to Administrator with root privileges. Since I am accessing db library and trying to work with it mongo throws error. Most interesting is that when I run all from method main everything works correctly. May be it somehow related to maven ? I can't even get a clue why ? P.S. thank you prasad_ for editing.

Comment: How are you accessing _mongo shell_? From the shell are you able to read and write data to the "libraray" database?

Comment: This is on how to [enable access control](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/) in MongoDB. Create a user administrator, first. Then user administrator can create other users with various functions / roles as needed, for example in this case a user with privileges to read and write to the "library" database. Use this user to authenticate from mongo shell or Java application to access (read/write) the data.

Comment: > use library
switched to db library
> db.books.insert ({name: "Java"})
WriteCommandError({
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "command insert requires authentication",
        "code" : 13,
        "codeName" : "Unauthorized"
})
>

Comment: library needs additional authentication or what ?

Comment: See my earlier comment on "enable access control".

Comment: I've got it, I will try to work it out. But why it runs (with reading/writing) in main method but fails in my code ? If role for library is not defined it should not give privileges to write/read when I run from main as well.

Comment: I can start a mongod  without the "auth" flag on the localhost and default port,  connect to the instance from the mongo shell, create a database (say "library"), add data to a "books"collection, query the data, etc. without any authentication. Also, access the "library" database and work with the data from a Java program, again without any authentication. Once, you start your mongod with auth flag, the authentication/authorization mechanism kicks in, and one has to follow the "rules".

Comment: Yea, good advise. It is better to get into mongodb without authentication first, get some experience and return to authentication. Thank you, I will follow your advise.

Comment: The problem was in uppercase Admin. Thank you prasad_ for indicating direction, will read mongodb  documentation.